проблема создания Jar-файла при работе с Maven
При изучении работы Maven, при отработке базовых навыков работы с Maven возникли трудности с версиями Maven.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaStart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>4.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Замените на ваш класс с методом main -->
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Проблема с
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>

Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.3.0' not found
указал 4.0.0
все равно получил в ответ: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:pom:4.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
требует Version : 4.0.0+
Подскажите пожалуйста как победить?

Версии 4.0.0 у этого плагина нет, последняя версия 3.7.1 от 18 марта 2024 г.

Благодарю, заработало. Подскажите пожалуйста как закрывать вопросы когда ответ получен?

Можете написать самоответ и принять его через какое-то время.

Да действительно последняя версия плагина 3.7.1 от 18 марта 2024 г., с ним все заработало.
